Is the word "retard" really spoken when some planes land?
I've been watching videos of plane landings, and I've noticed a certain word being said while some types of planes are very close to the ground. It sounds a lot like the word "retard," which surprises me since that word is often considered offensive. Is that really the word being said? If so, why is it being used in this context?

A simple search will show it's a common term in aviation: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=retard - the kids' slur is much more recent and unrelated.

@Therac They're not completely unrelated; they share a common root. The kid's slur comes from the no-longer-used medical term. In both cases (as well as when adjusting engine timings), it's being used as an antonym for 'to advance'; i.e. slow down or pull back.

There's lots of words that have a technical meaning and are also rude if used in a different context.

@SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica Common root, but one's a noun contraction from "mentally retarded" and the other's a verb. So their use is distinct both gramatically and phonetically.

You can tell someone's relatively young by how worked up they get over benign words like retard. Going to great lengths even to try avoiding saying it themselves.

It's a quite common term in physics: Retarded potential retarded time

Outside of aviation, you can also find road vehicles equipped with an indicator light assessing the mental capacity of the driver: "Retard on" dash light, what does it mean?

@SnakeDoc Yep, a person's age connects to where they're anchored in the history of "euphemism inflation" ... just like when people say "I remember when gas was 99 cents a gallon!"

The emphasis may be important here; when used as a verb, the emphasis is on the second syllable while when used as a (derogatory) noun it’s on the first.

@SnakeDoc Seems that depends entirely on your definition of the word "benign" and how widespread that definition is. The word "nigger" was considered benign by many just a few decades ago, and those people would have been wrong. For the record, I don't have a problem with "retard" because I've always used it and my social circles aren't generally the kind who would be offended by it, but I also have the tact not to use it among others because I know most nowadays wouldn't consider it benign, and I also think it's idiocy to pretend that old people are immune to being offended by words.

How in the world did this become a Hot Network Question on Stack Exchange?

It's surprising to see this question being so popular. Even today's young people must surely know there is a difference between calling someone 'retarded' as an insult, and 'mental retardation' as a medical diagnosis (for example). I refuse to believe the depressing alternative.

This reminds me of the computer user who made a furious call to the support line complaining that his computer was accusing him of being an invalid. The error message in question was "invalid user input." Words have multiple meanings, and technical jargon introduces still more meetings for words.

@HashimAziz, is it inherent to the word that it's not ok, or does it have something to do with the context it was used in, or the general state of race issues at the time?

@keshlam I wonder when people will start complaining about a dialogue with an "Ok" and a "Cancel" button.

@keshlam similarly, I have heard stories of complaints by patients against physicians for describing the patient as an "SOB". This is an an abbreviation for the common insult "Son Of a Bitch" but is also a medical term for "Shortness Of Breath".

What you're hearing is an automated callout on Airbus aircraft directing the pilots to retard the power to idle. It's a verb, used as an imperative.
If it were being used as a noun, or more specifically, if it was being used as an epithet for someone, then that would be offensive, but that's not the case here.

The two uses are also pronounced differently; the pejorative sense places stress on the first syllable, while the verb form places stress on the second (think "fire retardant").

The word means delay or hold back.  In this context it means to bring the engine power back.  In the pejorative sense it is a claim that a person is developmentally delayed.

@Anerdw Only that the Airbus callout places stress on the first syllable.

@AndreKR Wow, that is an...interesting decision. Well done, Airbus. I guess.

@Anerdw It might be synthesized speech instead of a recording, the text-to-speech system wouldn't know the context.

Or it's simply a direct translation of the word found in most romance languages, which literally have no other synonym for the concept of "delay" (unless you want to get fancy with the equivalent likes of "postpone" or "procrastinate")

ONLY on Airbus? I've heard this on many landing videos.

@MikeWaters Perhaps share a video link from a non-Airbus airliner?

Airbus uses the word "retard" for reducing the throttle on landing, and it's spoken by the proximity system.
Example from brake testing documentation:

Engines must be at idle at touchdown, with the throttles chopped to idle at the “RETARD” automatic call out.  At touchdown, manual braking is immediately applied to maximum pedal deflection

In some radio altimeter errors:

Heavy landing in AUTOLAND and a continuous RETARD call out.


Besides cutting the throttle, at what point would  reverse thrust be used? (I know, this probably deserves its own question. ;-)

You have actually answered this backwards. Airbus uses the word 'retard' to increase how much the engine is throttled, which means to reduce the power output. And the confusion with words like throttle is why a plain and unambiguous word like retard is used - it has only one interpretation, which is to reduce the power produced by the engines.

@fabspro Ah, there we go with ambiguous words again. Is “full throttle” a fast engine or one with low power? If “full throttle” and “throttle up” are equal, then retarding the throttle reduces it.

Throttling an engine literally means reducing the air intake, reducing the throttle is ambiguous. I was simply saying that your answer would have been clear if you had used a phrase like "reduce the engine power". I agree with you that "full throttle" and "throttle up" are ambiguous phrases as well.
